# Copying a set of specific files from a directory to another directory while retaining folder structure

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

I have a directory which looks like this:

```
\isa\documents\2004\2008\jac\file1.txt
\isa\documents\2004\jan\file1.txt
\isa\scannedDocs\2004\2009\jan\file2.pdf
\isa\documents\2005\2008\jac\file1.txt
\isa\documents\2003\jan\file1.txt
\isa\scannedDocs\2002\2009\jan\file2.pdf
```

I have a list of files I need copied (exported from a database), but because I don't need EVERY file in the directory, I only want the ones copied from my list:

Files-needed.txt:

```
\isa\documents\2004\2008\jac\file1.txt
\isa\documents\2004\jan\file1.txt
\isa\documents\2004\jac\file3.txt
\isa\documents\2003\jan\file1.txt
```

Basically:

1. I'll need to copy out the specific files needed, and
2. Log when a file can't be found, and,
3. I need folder structure retained, as the files might have the same name, just in different directories.

It's on a windows 7 machine, and I can run PowerShell and batch files. I tried robocopy and xcopy and either got all of the directories and no files or all files and no directories...

Any assistance would be great.

EDITS:

Okay, so i have tried Robocopy, but it is either copying the directories and no files or files and no directories. I haven't tried anything in powershell yet, but that might be the way...

It is Windows, I might have just written the slashes incorrectly above, I work between both environments, and was just trying to explain the problem.

Things I tried:

```
@echo off
set src_folder="C:\batchScripting\TEST_DIR\"
set dst_folder="C:\batchScripting\COPY2_DIR\"
robocopy "C:\batchScripting\TEST_DIR" "C:\batchScripting\COPY2_DIR" FileList.txt /S /V /NP /LOG:"log.log" /R:10 /W:30
```

and

```
 @echo off
 set src_folder=C:\batchScripting\TEST_DIR\
 set dst_folder=C:\batchScripting\COPY2_DIR\
 for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File-list.txt) DO xcopy /s /i "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Reading the `files-needed.txt`? Checking wether file exists or is missing? Actual copying? Something entirely different?

Comment: In addition to what vonPryz says, what have you tried?  http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: If the `directory` uses forward-slashes, then it's not Windows/Batch.  Did you mean to use back-slashes?  Does the list from the database really use forward-slashes?  I can think of a couple of ways to do this.  Providing the code for your failed attempts would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q23221996.txt) DO (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%%%a" (ECHO f|xcopy /y "%sourcedir%%%a" "%destdir%%%a" 2>NUL >nul
 ) ELSE (ECHO "%sourcedir%%%a" does NOT exist)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q23221996.txt` containing your data for my testing. `sourcedir` and `destdir` are both set up to suit my system.

The /y on the `xcopy` command forces overwrite if the destination file already exists.